# Translating "may have been": "puede haber sido" or "fuese/fuera"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, verbos

Just wondering how to phrase the following: "He may have been a bad person".

Would it be *"Quizá puede haber sido una mala persona"* or *"Quizá fuese/fuera una mala persona"*?

I would go for the latter but am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually remove *"quizás"* and use either of these:

- *Puede que haya sido una mala persona.*
- *Puede que fuera una mala persona.*

The difference lies in the "temporal distance": if "being a bad person" happened a long time ago, then *"puede que fuera"* reflects that fact. If instead it happened recently, then *"puede que haya sido"* is closer in time.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme,Walen